# Ionic2: how to catch events from within a Modal component (created from ModalController)?

Tags: ionic2

Is there a way to catch local events emitted from within a Modal component (created with ModalController) without dismissing, and not have to use the global `Events` or a service?

The Angular way to do this is to use `listen` from [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html#!#listen-anchor), but I don't see how to get the proper reference to the component instance in this case.

**MyComponent.ts**

```
...
export class MyComponent {
  @Output() myAwesomeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  fireEvent() {
    this.myAwesomeEvent.emit('payload');
  }
}
```

**Parent.ts**

```
...
const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyComponent);
// how do I catch 'myAwesomeEvent' emitted from within MyComponent?
...
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I think your modal variable will have instance property and from that you can get myAwesomeEvent so modal.instance.myAwesomeEvent.subscribe(...

Comment: @misha130 Exactly what I needed.  Set up an answer and I will accept.

Comment: TIP: set up the handler using `modal.didEnter` to make sure the `instance` member is available.  [See Docs on ViewController for details](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/ViewController/)

Comment: i am getting error modal.didEnter is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `instance` property in modal.

```
const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyComponent);
modal.didEnter.subscribe(() => {
    modal.instance.myAwesomeEvent.subscribe(....)
});
```

Ionic Version 3:

```
this.modalCtrl.create(MyComponent).present().then((result) =>{
    result.instance.myAwesomeEvent.subscribe(....)
});
```

Comment: its not working. I am getting error didEnter is not defined for modal

Comment: Note that this is ionic2 version. I added an edit answer for ionic 3

Comment: Still couldn't get it working with ionic3. `instance` doesn't seem to be a a defined property.

Comment: I guess it was supposed to be result.instance?

Comment: hi @misha130 is there any solution for ionic 5, .present().then((result) =>{ console.log(result)}); this is always undefined

Answer (score 5):

**IONIC version 4** this may be a workaround? (seems work fine in my app)

```
let eventEmitter= new EventEmitter();
eventEmitter.subscribe(res=>{
  console.log("emitterResult", res)
});

  const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: MyComponent,
  componentProps: {
    clickFavorite: eventEmitter
  }
});
```

myComponent:

```
export class MyComponent{    
@Output() clickFavorite= new EventEmitter<any>();

  favorite(evt){
      this.clickFavorite.emit("OK");}
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me in Ionic v5. Any explanation for this? Why do you create an emitter on the receiving end?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 5 +

Create an event emitter and add it in the `componentProps` attribute of the modal.
Then, in the modal component, add the `@Output` decorator on this event.
Subscribe to this event in the `modal.present()` promise.

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: ModalComponent,
      cssClass: 'custom-modal-class-2',
      componentProps: { modalActionObserver: this.modalActionObserver, ActionEvent: new EventEmitter<any>() },
      backdropDismiss: true,
      initialBreakpoint: 0.6,
      breakpoints: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1],
    });

    modal.present().then((result: any) => {
      modal.componentProps.ActionEvent.subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
      //do some action here
        }
      });


export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() ActionEvent
}
```